# Other language in JSON-LD than English

Tags: json-ld

I have a recipe website and am trying to put the JSON-LD in the head of the page. This whole website is in Indonesian and I was wondering it it's allowed to use an other language than English in JSON-LD? So instead of writing:

"recipeCategory": "Breakfast",

"recipeCuisine": "Indonesian",

can I write:

"recipeCategory": "Sarapan",

"recipeCuisine": "Indonesia",

Or do I need to define the language first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are no restrictions on language, but you may want to indicate the default language for strings using `@language` in your context. Note that any vocabulary you use might seem to be in English, but they are actually just shortcuts for URIs, and can always be aliases to Indonesian, if you like.

Depending on your consumers, you may want to be multi-lingual, and might consider using language maps.

JSON-LD is based on the RDF data model, and there is no bias towards any language expected for the data. Due to JSON, and also in RDF, you are restricted to UTF-8, though.

New in JSON-LD 1.1 is the ability to indicate text direction as well, although I don’t this this is necessarily useful for Indonesian.

Comment: Thanks Gregg. I tried to add at.language directly below at.context but that gives and error. In the case of recipeCategory, where do I need to add at.language? The error I get is: The property @language is not recognized by Google for an object of type Recipe

Comment: It needs to go inside `@context`

Comment: Sorry Greeg I keep on getting errors. My code starts with `<script type="application/ld+json">{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Recipe",`
How can I put it inside `@context`?

Comment: WendiT, probably too much to get into here. Best experiment on the JSON-LD Playground (https://json-ld.org/playground), where you can create a URL that re-creates the state you're concerned about. The Gitter.im interface is easier to use for going back and forth (https://gitter.im/json-ld/json-ld.org).

Comment: Thank you Gregg. I didn't know those sites. I'm going to give it a try there.

Comment: @WendiT use this: `{"@context": ["http://schema.org/", {"@language": "en"}]}`, and that's how you get to put things inside @context